# How can I identify and replace <img> tags that refer to images outside of my site?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to have all image links outside of my site blocked. How can I do this?

ex. I want to accept

```
http://www.mysite.com/notnecessary/notnecessary/possible.jpg 
http://mysite.com/notnecessary/notnecessary/possible.jpg 
http://www.mysite.com/possible.gif
```

but not

```
http://www.google.com/notnecessary/notnecessary/possible.jpg
http://www.othersite.net/notnecessary/notnecessary/possible.jpg
```

I'm doing this to try prevent hacking :) But I still want to be able to include my site's images. using

```
`<img src=""></img>`
```

---

Edit:

If I have a comment that says:

```
' Hello, these are images that contain a car 
<img src="http://mysite.com/possiblepath/car.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://www.othersite.com/w/e/car.gif"></img>
<img src='http://othersite.com/car.jpg'></img>

Which car is your favorite?'
```

So from this comment, I need:

```
' Hello, these are images that contain a car 
<img src="http://mysite.com/possiblepath/car.jpg"></img>
http://www.othersite.com/w/e/car.gif
http://othersite.com/car.jpg'

Which car is your favorite?'
```

My site img code should stay, others should turn into URLs/Links.

Thank you! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. Don't you control the link on your sites? Won't the said hacker be able to change your anti-hacker URL blocks? And why just images?

Comment: is `http://1.2.3.4/` allowed, where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of your site? What about: foo.jpeg, foo.tif, foo.tiff, foo.png, foo.bmp, etc?

Comment: Oh, what about relative links? Do you actually keep full URLs inside your site?

Comment: @Kobi I am fine with the files on my site. However, I allow people to post comments on my site. I do not want to have people posting other site content onto my site. Lets say a image that contains a virus from another site. For example http://theirsite.com/virus.jpg

Comment: Darius - you are now asking a *completely different question*! The main question I have now is: How do you sanitize your HTML?

Comment: We're just using strip_tags($content, "<script><img>") and htmlentities. We are doing this in php.

Answer (score 1):

`^http://(.*)mysite.com(.*)$`

That should work for you. You may need to add \'s before the parenthesis though, depending on what you are parsing it with. It will match if the given url belongs to mysite.com or any of its subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
^https?://(\w+\.)*mysite\.com($|[/?#&])
```

notes:

- `(\w+\.)` is a *simplistic* idea of what your sub domain may hold. If you're only interested in `www`, you can change that.
- `($|[/?#&])` - check for the end of the string or one of `/`, `?`, `#` or `&` directly after `mysite.com`. You want to avoid `http://mysite.com.example.com`, `http://example.com/mysite.com`,  `http://example.com?source=mysite.com`, etc.
- Don't check file extension unless you're going to white-list it, but it is rather useless anyway. Any URL may hide an image -  a server may return any file for any request.

Comment: If I have a comment that says:

' Hello, these are images that contain a car 
<img src="http://mysite.com/possiblepath/car.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://www.othersite.com/w/e/car.gif"></img>
<img src='http://othersite.com/car.jpg'></img>

Which car is your favorite?'

So from this comment, I need:

' Hello, these are images that contain a car 
<img src="http://mysite.com/possiblepath/car.jpg"></img>
http://www.othersite.com/w/e/car.gif
http://othersite.com/car.jpg'

Which car is your favorite?'

My site img code should stay, others should turn into URLs/Links.

Thank you! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
^https?://(?:www\.)?mysite\.com/

^           Start of line
http
s?          Maybe you have SSL??
://
(www.)?     With or without www. Similar to 
mysite
\.          Prevents "mysites"
com/
```